# Not getting the nested table containing company information using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get('http://indianindustriesdirectory.com/viewCompanyDetails.asp?compid=3855',headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

table = soup.find('table',{"width":"99%","cellpadding":"0","cellspacing":"0","border":"0"})

contact_person = table.find('b')

print(contact_person)
```

want all info about company but i am getting the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your library parser from `lxml` to `html.parser` and you will find all the data you want inside the `table` element.

Then you can apply a `find_all()` method on all `<tr>` of the table and explore the data

Code exemple:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('http://indianindustriesdirectory.com/viewCompanyDetails.asp?compid=3855',headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table',{"width":"99%","cellpadding":"0","cellspacing":"0","border":"0"})
trs = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    print(tr.get_text())
```

Answer (score 1):

The url you're referring to has several tables which look almost identical, so I picked one of them at random (`table[5]`, in this case). This code - which uses pandas, not BeautifulSoup, should get you a table which looks like the one on the page:

```
import pandas as pd  

all_tables = pd.read_html("http://indianindustriesdirectory.com/viewCompanyDetails.asp?compid=3855")

my_table = all_tables[5][[0,2]]
my_table.drop(my_table.tail(5).index,inplace=False).dropna(axis=0, how='all')
```

Comment: but how can we crawl the data inside trs and save it using panda.